# Unable to push array values dynamically comparing two arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two arrays in angular.

One is regular array A with values ['Stock_Number', 'Model', 'Type', 'Bill_Number']

Another is associated array B like the following

```
0:[
  {
    'Stock_Number': 'GTH738', 
    'Model': 'sample_model', 
    'Type': 'sample_type', 
    'Bill_Number': 7784754,
    'some_prop1': 'prop1_val',
    'some_prop2': 'prop2_val'
  }
];
```

Both arrays are dynamic. Also B has more columns than A. A has the keys of B's(A is subset of B) I want to get a new array C only for elements in A. For this I'm checking if key exists in B.  Following is my code

```
for(var i=0,j=0; i<B.length,j<A.length; i++,j++){
        if (!B.hasOwnProperty(A)) {
           var value = A[j];
                console.log('if-'+value); //printing value 
                console.log(B[0].value); // printing undefined 
               // C.push(B[0].value);
        }else{
            //some code
        }
    }
```

Resulting array should be something like the following

```
{
'Stock_Number': 'GTH738', 
'Model': 'sample_model', 
'Type': 'sample_type', 
'Bill_Number': 7784754
}
```

Can somebody suggest me how this can be achieved?

Comment: Could you clarify, in B, does it look like: `{ 0: [{'Stock_Number' ...`? The 0 is the property?

Comment: What is your desired structure for array C?

Comment: yeah, actually it's a JSON array getting through API result. It's the index

Comment: @Ankit it would be as associated array just like B with stock number and related value

Comment: please select an example where the wanted result (please add that as well) is kind of possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach. For better example on what you need I have added some extra properties on object of B array which is not in array A. Thus, those properties are excluded from the objects in array C

```js
var A = ['Stock_Number', 'Model', 'Type', 'Bill_Number'];
var B = [
  {
    'Stock_Number': 'GTH738', 
    'Model': 'sample_model', 
    'Type': 'sample_type', 
    'Bill_Number': 7784754
  },
  {
    'Stock_Number': 'GTH740', 
    'Model': 'sample_model2', 
    'Type': 'sample_type2', 
    'Bill_Number': 7784754,
    'someProp1': 1,
    'someProp2': 2,
  }
];

var C = [];
for(var i=0; i<B.length; i++){
  var obj = B[i];
  var objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
  var resObj = {};
  A.forEach(function(itemA){
    if(objKeys.indexOf(itemA) !== -1){
      resObj[itemA] = obj[itemA];
    }
  });
  C.push(resObj);
}

console.log(C);
```

Comment: B has only one object, not  multiple objects. I edited my B it would look like mine

Comment: includes keyword doesn't work in angular. Any alternative?

Comment: you can use `indexOf`. I have updated my answer using that. @Esco

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the line

```
console.log(B[0].value);
```

with

```
console.log(B[0][value]);
```

Comment: It doesn't allow that way

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the unknown keys and build a new object out of the surplus keys.

```js
var arrayA = ['Stock_Number', 'Model', 'Type', 'Bill_Number'],
    arrayB = [{ Stock_Number: 'GTH738', Model: 'sample_model', Type: 'sample_type', Bill_Number: 7784754 }, { Stock_Number: 'GTH738', Model: 'sample_model', Type: 'sample_type', Bill_Number: 7784754, foo: 'bar', baz: 42 }],
    result = [];

arrayB.forEach(function (b) {
    keys = Object.keys(b).filter(k => !arrayA.includes(k));
    if (keys.length) {
        result.push(Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: b[k] }))));
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var A = ['Stock_Number', 'Model', 'Type', 'Bill_Number'];
var B = [
  {
    'Stock_Number': 'GTH738', 
    'Model': 'sample_model', 
    'Type': 'sample_type', 
    'Bill_Number': 7784754
  },
  {
    'Stock_Number': 'GTH740', 
    'Model': 'sample_model2', 
    'Type': 'sample_type2', 
    'Bill_Number': 7784754,
    'someProp1': 1,
    'someProp2': 2,
  }
];

var C = B.map(item =>{
    let obj = {};
    A.forEach(key => {
        obj[key] = item[key];
    });
    return obj;
});
```